# How to set initial size of Console window in RCP application

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working on RCP application, in my application one composite is there at first half horizontal space and after that Console window is there.
But the size if console window is small when I opens RCP application and there is much space between console window and other elements in above composite.
Please refer below screenshot for initial size of console when I open RCP app :

Initial Size Of Console:
[image: Initial Size Of Console]

And I want initial size of console is like :
[image: Expected Size Of Console]

So each time I have to resize console manually when I opens RCP app.

I have used consolePageParticipants extension in RCP app :

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePageParticipants">
   <consolePageParticipant
      id="com.example.ExamplePageParticipant"
      class="com.example.ExamplePageParticipant">
   </consolePageParticipant>
</extension>
```

How can I set initial size of console window in RCP application?
Could you please help me with it?

Thanks In Advance!!

Comment: What "console window"? RCP apps are normal GUIs and don't have a console. If this is some window you have written in SWT you need to show us a [mre]

Comment: I have used consolePageParticipants extension in RCP app :                        
 `<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePageParticipants">
          <consolePageParticipant id="com.example.ExamplePageParticipant"
            class="com.example.ExamplePageParticipant">
          </consolePageParticipant>
 </extension>`                                 and removed some constributionItems from its toolbar by overriding init() method of ConsolePageParticipants. And I am printing sysouts and errors in console window.

Comment: Still not enough info. Are you using a perspective layout for that? If so what does it look like, if not what are you using?

Comment: How did you add the _Console_ view to your(?) perspective? See https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse3RCP/article.html#add-the-view-to-your-perspective

Comment: Thank you so much for all your inputs!! It gave me a hint to resolve my issue  I will put resolution in answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had added upper view in perspective(`org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions`) but in relative there was `org.eclipse.ui.editorss`.
Now, I have changed relative as `org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView` and added ratio and relationship of upperview as top :

```
<perspectiveExtension
        targetID="*">
     <view
           id="<My Upper View ID'"
           minimized="false"
           ratio="0.30"
           relationship="top"
           relative="org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsoleView">
     </view>
  </perspectiveExtension>
```

This resolved my issue.

Thank you so much for all your inputs!